# Qt tr does not seem to work on static constant members?

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I'm working on translating our Qt gui at the moment.

I have the following code:

```
// header file
static const QString Foo;

// cpp file
const QString FooConstants::Foo = "foo"; 

// another cpp file
editMenu->addAction(tr(FooConstants::Foo));
```

This doesn't seem to work though.

That is, there is no entry in the .ts file for the above constant.

If I do this then it works:

```
// another cpp file
editMenu->addAction(tr("foo"));
```

However, this constant is used in many places, and I don't want to have to manually update each string literal. (if it were to change in the future)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not use a define: 
#define Foo tr("foo")

Comment: @Patrice: Because it would cause more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I haven't used tr much, but why not do:
const QString FooConstants::Foo = QObject::tr("foo");

Comment: @Bill: That would mean than the text is hardcoded to "foo". Constants will be initialized before translations can be added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wrap your literal in the [`QT_TR_NOOP`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_TR_NOOP) macro:

```
// cpp file
const QString FooConstants::Foo = QT_TR_NOOP("foo");
```

From the [guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c):

> If you need to have translatable text completely outside a function, there are two macros to help: QT_TR_NOOP() and QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(). They merely mark the text for extraction by the lupdate tool. The macros expand to just the text (without the context).

Answer (score 2):

As Thomas mentioned, you have to use a macro.

The reason is that Qt doesn't know which strings to translate by default, it scans the files and looks for a set of patterns. One of them is `tr("text")`, but if you want to use a constant, you will have to mark it explicitly with `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` or `QT_TR_NOOP` when it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
editMenu->addAction(tr(FooConstants::Foo));
```

I think your problem is that tr takes a char* argument, not a QString:

```
QString QObject::tr ( const char * sourceText, const char * disambiguation = 0, int n = -1 )
```

You could change the type of FooConstants::Foo, or convert it to a char* when you create the menu action, for example:

```
 const QByteArray byteArray = FooConstants::Foo.toLatin1();
 char *data = byteArray.data();
 editMenu->addAction(tr(data));
```